# How to add a cut string in the list with javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a small problem with the JavaScript. I would like to add the string (format:one-two-three) the list, but this cut the sign ("-") and every elements tag add. I try solve this problem, unfortunatelly don't succeeded. Here my function:

function listAdd(){

```
var string = document.forms["form1"].elements["stringAdd"].value;
if(string != ""){
    var array = string.split("");
    var eredmeny = array.some(function(v) { return v == "-";});
    if(eredmeny){
        for(var i = 0; i <array.length; i++){
            if(array[i] != "-"){
                var newElement = document.createElement('li');
            array[i] = array.toString();
            newElement.textContent = array[i];

            var list = document.getElementById("gyumi");
            list.appendChild(list.createTextNode(array[i]));
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        var newElement = document.createElement('li');
        newElement.textContent = szoveg;

        var list = document.getElementById("gyumi");
        list.appendChild(newElement); 
        }



    }
```

}

Sorry, poor my English and this is the first question to me.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're saying you have a string like `"one-two-three"` and you want to split that up on the `-` and add the resulting `"one"`, `"two"`, and `"three"` to the list.

If so, you want to use `split("-")` rather than `split("")` and you don't need the `some` to check for `-`. Also, you can use `createTextNode` to put in the list item content (`textContent` is not cross-browser compatible), and you only need to get the list once:

```js
function listAdd() {
  var string = document.forms["form1"].elements["stringAdd"].value;
  if (string != "") {
    var list = document.getElementById("gyumi");
    string.split("-").forEach(function(entry) {
      var newElement = document.createElement('li');
      newElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry));
      list.appendChild(newElement);
    });
  }
}
listAdd();
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input type="text" name="stringAdd" value="one-two-three">
</form>
<ul id="gyumi"></ul>
```

That works even if there is no `-` in the string, because `split("-")` will return just a single element in the array if there are no `-` in the string.

Comment: Thanks your answer! :) It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption here is that you're trying to create `li` items from a string that is delimited by the '-' character. Should that be true, see the following:

You can split your string into it's subcomponents by the `.split()` function as you've used and then iterate over those elements and create the list items and append them to the body of the document.

```js
var mystr = 'one-two-three';

var components = mystr.split('-');

components.forEach(function(comp){
  var item = document.createElement('li');
  item.textContent = comp;
  // set your attrs on the item here
  document.body.appendChild(item);
});
```

Comment: The OP's use of `textContent` was good. Don't suggest using `innerHTML` for this.

Comment: Thanks your answer. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `split`, but it becomes a lot easier if you split by `-`. Then you have exactly the values you want to add to the list.

Secondly, if you run this function when the form is submitted, or on the click of a form button, make sure to cancel the form submission.

Finally, you will want to clear in the input when the items have been added to the list.

```js
function listAdd() {
    var inp = document.forms["form1"].elements["stringAdd"];
    var list = document.getElementById("gyumi");
    var string = inp.value;
    if (string != "") {
        string.split('-').forEach(function (item) { // split by the hyphen
            var newElement = document.createElement('li');
            newElement.textContent = item;
            list.appendChild(newElement); // not a text node
        });
    }
    // clear input once you have added the items:
    inp.value = '';
    return false; // cancel form submission
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" onsubmit="return listAdd()">
    Items: <input name="stringAdd"> [Press enter to add]
</form>
<ul id="gyumi"></ul>
```